# Redirect output of irssi to file

Tags: shell, irc, irssi

I'm using irssi v1.1.2 as an IRC client and I'm trying to redirect the output of a command to a file. For example the output of `/list` command is:

```
/list *[Mm]ex*
00:01 Matched #supremexpasswords
00:01 Matched #mexico
00:01 Matched #mp3mexico
00:01 Matched #Mexic
...
00:01 End of /LIST
```

How to redirect the output to a file? I tried `/help` but didn't find any command to redirect output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The command `/lastlog` can save the output of the current window to a file:

```
/lastlog -file output.txt
```